# How can I add a css class to an element with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

tried code below
returned Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add'). The class 'form-control' is on all inputs

```
const forms = ".form-control";
if (device.name === "Panel") {
    await page.evaluate((s) => {
        let dom = document.querySelectorAll(s);
        dom.classList.add("_has_error");
    }, forms);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements. You can try `dom.classList` is `undefined` indeed as the error says, but `dom[0].classList` gives valid DOM token list.

You need to iterate over the `dom` array, e.g. with `Array.forEach()` if you want to apply your class on every matching elements:

```js
let dom = document.querySelectorAll(s);
dom.forEach(el => el.classList.add("_has_error"));
```